# multithreading in Ruby vs JRuby vs Java

Tags: java, jruby

I am new to Ruby and the JRuby and I was trying to implement multithreaded code in Ruby and came to know that GIL doesn't allow my code to run in parallel then I moved to JRuby and implemented the same code and my execution time in JRuby was much better than the Ruby. I studied that JRuby threading is very much similar to threading in Java, so I implemented the same in code in Java as well and I got a performance(execution time) in Java to be almost 10x faster than JRuby, can someone explain me the reason for this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Ruby is a dynamic language which is usually slower to execute than a static language such as Java. Various optimisers exist for dynamic languages which improve performance (ie. a lot of work has gone into speeding up javascript in browsers). But because of the fundamental principals of the language, dynamic languages have inherent performance disadvantages. Performance and static compile time safety / vs speed of development and ad hoc hackibilty are the main pro / con arguments between static and dynamic languages.

Comment: thanks @slipperyseal for your suggestion, is there any particular reason for the performance difference between the static and dynamic typed languages while implementing multithreading? I mean any difference between the execution of thread or something like that?

Comment: not in itself. not unless you have lots of contention on locks or spin locks (which a modern JVM won't do - modern JVM synchronisation is very fast). I think your issues come down to simply: Ruby code running on JRuby is simply slower than the equivalent regular Java code.

Comment: you can rule it out by doing some benchmarks tests on a single threaded code. if JRuby is still just as slow you know it cant be an issue with multi-threading

Comment: I'll try it, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

the explanation is quite simple when you think about JRuby being Ruby implemented in Java, which means that you have 'more' Java code to execute using the .rb piece compared to plain .java compiled to a .class ...

than even if the method dispatch was cost-less there's the dynamic nature of Ruby e.g. when you `a+1` on Java it adding to ints while `a+1` in Ruby its an addition with overflow checks etc.

your question is quite general and we also do not know what kind of performance measuring you did but in the end it all comes down to productivity when you do 'real-world' work + with JRuby if you feel like some part is worth being 10x faster you still have the option of re-doing that piece in "native" Java.